Automatic merge went well; stopped before committing as requested
I want to merge one feature branch into another, without merge commit.
Both feature branches have been branched from the same main development branch.
Let's say I have this setup:
        |-- feature_a -- commit #1 -- commit #2
develop |
        |-- feature_b -- commit #3

And what I want to have as a result after merging is:
        |-- feature_a -- commit #1 -- commit #2 -- commit #3
develop |
        |-- feature_b -- commit #3

I tried to do the merge using following command, while feature_a is checked out:
git merge feature_b --no-commit --ff

I receive the message Automatic merge went well; stopped before committing as requested.
Unfortunately I have no explanation for this message and no idea at the moment how to resolve this "problem" in a correct way.
In my opinion the merge should have worked, escpecially regarding the fact that feature_a and feature_b were branched from the same branch and contain therefore mainly the same commit history.
Furthermore both branches face totally different sources. So the source of feature_a are fully disjunct of feature_b's sources.
Anyone an idea?

--no-commit -> stopped before committing as requested?!

Do you want to merge or rebase/cherry-pick?

It seems that you do not realize what git merge is. When you say git merge, you are asking Git to create a new commit — a merge commit. Git constructs this commit in your working tree; that is, it enacts the merge by actually changing the files in your working tree, and then it does an add-and-commit to complete the construction of the merge commit.
When you said --no-commit, however, you said: Git, please enact the merge in my working tree but do not actually complete the merge by making the merge commit. So it didn't, and it told you so. Everything went fine, says Git; I was able to enact the merge in your working tree, but you told me not to make the merge commit and I did not.
If you like what happened, and you want to complete the merge, it is up to you now to say git commit — because you told Git not to say it. If you do not like what happened, just say git reset --hard to remove Git's operations from your working tree.

You seem also to have had some expectation that this would be a fast forward (you said --ff), but you were wrong about that so Git ignored that instruction. A fast-forward is not a merge and does not make a merge commit. But Git could not do the fast-forward so it did a true merge, omitting the final commit as you instructed.

And it looks like OP is looking for a squash "merge" (which is not a real merge and introduces all sorts of problems).

@knittl Actually if we take the OP seriously it looks to me more like a cherry-pick was desired (though we cannot take the OP seriously, because "commit #3" cannot be in two places at once). I did not address that entire part of the question, though ("what I want"). I think that should be a different question. I responded only to "Unfortunately I have no explanation for this message and no idea at the moment how to resolve this "problem" in a correct way."
